# In subgroup analysis, some coefficients of predictors are insignificant, if full analysis is preformed, the coefficients of predictors are significant

Tags: regression, time-series, poisson-regression, distributed-lag

I have a set of data including information of age groups, education level, and meteorological data from 2000 to 2006.

The dataset was spilt by age groups(65-74,75-84,85+),education level(university or above, other), weather (summer, winter),
and run the following regression:

```
Death ~ Temp_lag3 + NO3 + rainfall + relative_humidity, family = quasipoisson()
```

However, the coefficient of `Temp_lag3` is insignificant.

If I run full model regression:

```
Death ~ Temp_lag3 + NO3 + rainfall + relative_humidity + age_group + education + weather, family = quasipoisson()
```

The coefficient of `Temp_lag3` becomes significant. Also, the coefficients of age_group are significant.

How do we interpret such contradictory results?

Comment: If you use the "dredge" function of the MuMIn package, is Temp-lag3 supported in the models within a delta AIC of 2 ?

Comment: Would you mind to explain why "dredge" function will relate to my question? The dataset used in subgroup analysis is different from full model analysis. Can this function deal with sub group analysis too...? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand you had subsetted the data. It means that for the first model you provide, you ran one separate one on each age class ?

Comment: Yes, I mean `Death ~ Temp_lag3 + NO3 + rainfall + relative_humidity, family = quasipoisson(), subset = (age_group='65-74')` etc.

Answer (score 2):

By subsetting the data, you are decreasing the sample size available for the detection of your simple effects. When you consider your whole dataset together on the other hand, you increase the detection power of these effects.
Note that it is incorrect to subset your dataset by age class if you want for example to know whether Temp_lag3 has a different effect in one age class compared to the other. For this you would need to test for the interaction between Temp_lag3 and age class in your whole dataset.

Comment: Would you mind to explain why it is incorrect to subset your dataset by age class if you want for example to know whether Temp_lag3 has a different effect in one age class compared to the other? The reason why I did sub-group analysis was the assumption of heterogeneity of heat/ cold effects in sub-groups.